# Error Request HTTP from Windows OS

Tags: windows, http, nginx, server, request

Now i'm using nginx for serve differents kind of service and only when I send a request to my server from Windows, my server response a 400 error, the access logs file says this:

```
63.143.42.248 - - [22/Nov/2017:14:12:30 +0100] "\x00\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
63.143.42.248 - - [22/Nov/2017:14:12:30 +0100] "\x00\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
63.143.42.248 - - [22/Nov/2017:14:12:51 +0100] "\x00\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
63.143.42.248 - - [22/Nov/2017:14:13:30 +0100] "\x00\x00T / HTTP/1.1" 400 166 "-" "-"
63.143.42.248 - - [22/Nov/2017:14:13:51 +0100] "\x00\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
83.37.168.15 - - [22/Nov/2017:14:14:01 +0100] "\x00\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
83.37.168.15 - - [22/Nov/2017:14:14:03 +0100] "\x00\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
83.37.168.15 - - [22/Nov/2017:14:14:03 +0100] "\x00\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
83.37.168.15 - - [22/Nov/2017:14:14:04 +0100] "\x00\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
83.37.168.15 - - [22/Nov/2017:14:14:04 +0100] "\x00\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
83.37.168.15 - - [22/Nov/2017:14:14:04 +0100] "\x00\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
83.37.168.15 - - [22/Nov/2017:14:14:10 +0100] "\x00\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
83.37.168.15 - - [22/Nov/2017:14:14:10 +0100] "\x00\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
83.37.168.15 - - [22/Nov/2017:14:14:10 +0100] "\x00\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
```

with Unix based-systems don't have any problems.

Any sugestions?
I've been banging my head againts this issue for 2 weeks.

PD: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I found the solution, this was a error for a intermediate router.